Issue in Removing server header in nginx:alpine docker container
Im going to remove server header from nginx response so I came with following:
this is my docker-compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx_with_modified_header
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - E:\TestProject\Nginx-Docker\Version-2\nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - E:\TestProject\Nginx-Docker\Version-2\conf-data:/PejiWebsites/

and dockerfile:
FROM nginx:alpine

#RUN apk add --no-cache nginx-mod-http-headers-more
RUN apk add nginx-mod-http-headers-more

EXPOSE 8080

and alos in nginx.conf i add more_clear_headers 'Server'; in the http section,
but when i run docker-compose up i will get following:

nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "more_clear_headers" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:28

what is the problem?
